# Dynamic Dependent Dropdown for Board, Medium & Standard

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dropdown

I'm trying to create dynamic dependent dropdown. In which user first select board after that board medium are loaded and after selecting medium standard are loaded. It similar to dropdown of Countries, states & cities.

Here are attached code. Dropdown are not working fine. When i select board, medium dropdown are not loaded and showing blank. Please anyone find error and give me the solution for it. Thank you...

index.php

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#board').on('change',function(){
        var boardID = $(this).val();
        if(boardID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'board_id='+boardID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#medium').html(html);
                    $('#standard').html('<option value="">Select medium first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#medium').html('<option value="">Select board first</option>');
            $('#standard').html('<option value="">Select medium first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#medium').on('change',function(){
        var mediumID = $(this).val();
        if(mediumID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'medium_id='+mediumID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#standard').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#standard').html('<option value="">Select medium first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
//Include the database configuration file
include 'db_connect.php';

//Fetch all the country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ag_board WHERE board_status = 1 ORDER BY board_name ASC");


//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select id="board">
    <option value="">Select Board</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['board_unique_id'].'">'.$row['board_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">board not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>

<select id="medium">
    <option value="">Select board first</option>
</select>

<select id="standard">
    <option value="">Select medium first</option>
</select>
```

ajaxData.php

```
<?php
//Include the database configuration file
include 'db_connect.php';

if(!empty($_POST["board"])){
    //Fetch all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ag_medium WHERE board_unique_id = ".$_POST['board_unique_id']." AND medium_status = 1 ORDER BY medium_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //State option list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select medium</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['medium_unique_id'].'">'.$row['medium_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Medium not available</option>';
    }
}elseif(!empty($_POST["medium_unique_id"])){
    //Fetch all city data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ag_standard WHERE medium_unique_id = ".$_POST['medium_unique_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY std_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //City option list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Standard</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['std_unique_id'].'">'.$row['std_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Std not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php
//Database credentials
$dbHost     = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName     = 'db_aneri';

//Connect and select the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Can you explain what you mean by "Dropdown(s) are not working fine. "? Being specific is more helpful.

Comment: @rainer i mean when i select board in first dropdown the medium in second dropdown are not loaded.

Comment: Good info. Ideally, you edit your question and put the the clarification there. This is just to help you getting started on SO...